What is the minSdkVersion for targetSdkVersion 34?
What is the minSdkVersion for targetSdkVersion 34 ?
Can I build for minSdkVersion 21 and with targetSdkVersion 34?
No warning in Android studio?

Properties targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion are deprecated and are now being called targetSdk and minSdk. And there is no rule for minSdk. According to Android API Levels, minSdk 21 would be the least, based on these constraints:

Jetpack/AndroidX libraries require a minSdk of 21 or higher since April 2024.
Jetpack Compose requires a minSdk of 21 or higher.
Google Play services v23.30.99+ (August 2023) drops support for API levels below 21.

Better use minSdk 22 or even minSdk 23, in order not having to support Android 5.
This is a matter of effort, while Android 5 and 6 do behave quite differently at times.
These "warnings" obviously come from not dealing properly with code deprecation.

In order to support older devices (eg. minSdk 19 and maxSdk 22), it may be easier to create a modern (Jetpack) and  legacy (Support Library) product-flavor, with Jetifier disabled, because the constraints are based on this one library. The Java Version to use, also changed over time.
